# Angular disable button after moving away from component

Tags: angular

I have a form and with some input fields and a button. 
After filling the form and clicking the button I open a modal which has table of data (as per the form values from `component1` selections.)

User then selects some data from this modal. Once user is done and closes the modal, I show another third component of selected values. FYI I am storing these selected values via my service as well.

I need to disable this button once the user selects some data from my modal, and if they deselect the data I want to enable this button.

How can I enable/disable this button as while checking the data selection (*i.e.* if data was selected in modal) in `component1`. Since its already loaded that doesn't works.

Below is some of my relevant code.

**Button:**

```
 <button (click)="clicked()" type="button" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled" class="btn default">Click</button>
```

**Component:**

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  isButtonDisabled: boolean:false;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.myService.getSelectedData().length>0 {
       this.isButtonDisabled = true; 
     }else{
        this.isButtonDisabled = false; 
    }
 }
}
```

`myService` below holds the data when the user makes selections or removes selections.

```
this.myService.getSelectedData()
```

So I thought checking this in my `ngOnit` of `component1` would work but then I realize the `component1` is already loaded.

Could anyone point the solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. You basically want to disable button in component 1, based on event in component 2 right ? If so, why don't you use a Shared Service and a Subject / BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I am already using shared service as I mentioned in my post. I am also using an Subject there. But if I use this then that means I have tosubscribe to this in my component 1 right?

Comment: Nadhir's solution is the most simple one. Otherwise you would have had to subscribe into your cpt indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you service public as below:
`constructor(public myService: MyService) {}`

and in your template you can check directly the function like this:

`[disabled]="myService.getSelectedData().length > 0`

and you can get rid of the code inside `ngOninit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngAfterContentInit` method in your component.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit

```js
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
  isButtonDisabled: boolean:false;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(this.myService.getSelectedData().length>0 {
       this.isButtonDisabled = true; 
     }else{
        this.isButtonDisabled = false; 
    }
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Rafael this does not work. Once all the content is loaded I want to then enable and disable button.